# How to show modalviewcontroller above tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have tab bar and in view "A" and in "A" I have navigation controller. SO inside my navigation controller in "A" i called

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES]
```

But modalView shows under tab bar. How to show it above tab bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this is that the ancestor viewController is not correctly set.
for instance imagine:

```
UIViewController * myController = ... // a view controller without a proper ancestor
```

now:

```
myController.tabBarController == nil
```

Therefore:

```
[myController presentModalViewController:otherController];
```

Will fail (by showing up under the tab bar).  The fix is to add myController to its ancestor via

```
[parentController addChildViewController:myController];
```

Now, `parentController` must be added to another controller in the same way and so forth until the root one is your tabController.  This is only available in iOS 5+.  If build for iOS 4 or earlier, you will have to work around this by making sure all of your controllers are directly added to either a UINav or UITab controller.  If this is not possible, you will have to access the UITabBarController via a global variable.

Comment: I used global variable. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

Try to present modal view from `UITabBarController`:

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

My case, the modal has a transparent background, I set `modalPresentationStyle` is `.overFullScreen` and it show at above tabbar with clear background.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the presented view controller had `UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext` at `.modalPresentationStyle`, which made the `tab bar` overlap

Jus switch back to a default value to fix the issue

Comment: Hey, Were you to able to solve this issue. I'm facing the same issue. :|

Comment: @YashBedi, yes, I set the modal presentation style to default one. In my case modal presentation style was changed from a default one by an accident